# Cannot access $scope properties after Closure compiler property renaming

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a controller like so:

```
/**
 * Widget Controller.
 * @param {!angular.Scope} $scope The current controller $scope.
 * @constructor
 * @ngInject
 * @export
 */
name.space.widgetController = function($scope) {
  /**
   * Scope reference.
   * @type {!angular.Scope}
   * @private
   */
  this.scope_ = $scope;

  // Get the initial widgets list...
  this.getWidgets_();
}

/**
 * Updates the current list of widgets.
 * @export
 */
name.space.widgetController.prototype.getWidgets = function() {
  this.scope_.widgets = name.space.WidgetsController.DEFAULT_WIDGETS_LIST_;
};


/**
 * The default widgets list.
 * @const {!Array.<{!Object}>}
 * @private
 */
name.space.WidgetsController.DEFAULT_WIDGETS_LIST_ = [
  {name: 'Foo', color: 'Orange'},
  {name: 'Bar', color: 'Black'}
];
```

And I have a template like so:

```
<pre>{{ widgets | json }}</pre>
<table class=" table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
      <td>{{ widget.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ widget.color}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Everything has compiled fine with the Closure compiler:

```
java -jar closure/compiler.jar \
    'src/app/**.js' '!**_test.js' 'vendor/closure-library/' \
    --angular_pass \
    --externs src/externs/**.js \
    --js_output_file public/javascripts/application.js \
    --generate_exports \
    --only_closure_dependencies \
    --closure_entry_point=name.space.app \
    --compilation_level='ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS' \
    --output_wrapper='(function(){%output%})();//# sourceMappingURL=application.js.map' \
    --create_source_map='./public/javascripts/application.js.map'
```

... But The template can't access the property. Upon inspection, my $scope.widgets is renamed to $scope.a. I can change the property to $scope['widgets'], and it works, but this doesn't seem right.

Any ideas what I can do to get the template to access the property correctly? It seems that templates somehow might need property renaming, too.

EDIT:
I *was* able to get this working with the `@expose` property (as I found with the link provided by [@Adobe Flex Coder 0622](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3268192/adobe-flex-coder-0622) below, but I still wonder if that is the correct way to approach this issue. The updated code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Updates the current list of widgets.
 * @export
 */
name.space.widgetController.prototype.getWidgets = function() {
  /** @expose */
  this.scope_.widgets = name.space.WidgetsController.DEFAULT_WIDGETS_LIST_;
};
```

EDIT:

I am conflicted even more now. `@expose` works... but according to this [Closure Error Reference](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref) page (see the heading _JSC_UNSAFE_NAMESPACE_), it is deprecated:

> There’s no easy fix, since @expose is deprecated and shouldn't be
>   used. If you want a property not to be obfuscated, access it as
>   this['sample'] instead of this.sample (you'll also need to fix all
>   references).

...What to do?

`scope['property'] = '...'?`?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article,[Google Closure Compiler](http://www.mircozeiss.com/a-radical-new-approach-to-developing-angularjs-apps/) the result your getting is accurate.  The one thing that you can also use is the $inject command. The controller command would look something like this.

```
   name.space.widgetController = function($scope) {
  /**
   * Scope reference.
   * @type {!angular.Scope}
   * @private
   */
  this.scope_ = $scope;

  // Get the initial widgets list...
  this.getWidgets_();
}
  widgetController.$inject("$scope");
```

Comment: That link was very helpful. As far as `$inject` goes, the compiler is doing that for me: `$inject=["$scope"]`:-(

However, I was able to get it working with expose:

`/** @expose */`
`this.scope_.widgets = '...'.`